# How can I manually open the Google app news/article push notification history?

Tags: notifications, google

The Google app (com.google.android.quicksearchbox) sends notifications. Some of these are suggested searches, while others are specific articles. These are separate from Google News. If I tap one of these articles, it will take me to a history of previous article notifications selected for me with the most recent one (probably the one just tapped) on top. However, once I navigate away from the list, I can't find any way to get back to it. It's not Discover, or at least not the page opened by opening the Google app and tapping Discover on the bottom left.  I can't find it in the "More" section, nor in long-pressing the shortcut to get the quick launch options (Nova Launcher).

Is there a way to deliberately navigate to this page?